# Find an 8 digit stock number within a cell

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, indexing, split, vlookup

I am looking to create a formula that enables me to search a set of data for an 8 digit number. I have attached my testing sheet.

In column B is the stock numbers I need to find within a set of data.

In column E is the full list to be checked against, however, within any one cell, you can have several different 8 digit stock numbers.

In my test sheet, I have found that a vlookup only searches for the first stock number and not all the stock numbers within that cell. I have attempted an index match formula combined with a transpose split however none of these has enabled me to properly search my data set.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B,$E$2:$E,1,0))`

then

`=INDEX($E$2:$E$1139,(MATCH(B2,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT($E$2:$E,";, ")))))`

The data can be separated within the cell with either spaces or "," or ";"

You should be able to make a copy of my test sheet using this link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UckPZw6tWBw0H13p79N94IqV2EFyfhYNyEhmLecr3XM/copy#gid=55962883

Hope you can help.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: The link has been updated. sorry about that

Comment: Can you share an example of the result you are trying to achieve? For what I am understanding the result should be to get the three numbers on yellow right?

Comment: If possible I would like a result similar to a vlookup. It can pull back the full stock numbers within column E, but I just want a flag within each row to highlight where a match has been found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(E:E, REGEXMATCH(E:E&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

to get true/false use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(E2:E&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)))
```

or if you want to return match or N/A use:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(E2:E&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)), E2:E, ISNA()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, while this does find the stock numbers within the dataset, I need it to identify the rows where there is a match in a similar way that a Vlookup would return a figure or N/A.

Comment: @JoelWhitmore answer updated

Comment: Thank you for your help, this has enabled me to pull together the following formula.

```=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";, ",1,QUERY(INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(E2:E&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)), E2:E, ISNA())),"Select * where not Col1 contains '#N/A'")),";, ")),1,0)))```

Comment: yes this has helped me to pull out the data needed.